# Merging Margins not working for Button

Tags: css

I'm trying to take control of the vertical spacing between all text tags like H1, H2, P etc. and buttons by assigning them all:

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p,
button { margin: 20px 0; }
```

As expected, this works fine for the text tags with their margins merging, i.e. a H1 followed by a Paragraph will have 20px spacing between them, not 40px. This isn't the case for buttons though. If I have:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<button>link</button>
```

The space between the paragraph and button is 40px, putting the button within a P tag fixes this but is that semantically correct?

Comment: Yes you can use a button in a paragraph. the content model of a paragraph is "phrasing content" and a button is phrasing content.

Comment: Ah well if that's the case then that's better since buttons used in places headers and such won't be effected. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: block` so the margins will collapse. But you can also use a button in a paragraph. The content model of a [p tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) is [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) and a button is phrasing content.

```css
h1,h2,h3,h4,p,button { margin: 20px 0; display: block; }
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<button>link</button>
```

Comment: I've just tried this but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Do you use `float: left/right` or flexbox? In that case margins are not collapsed.

Comment: Ah I'm an idiot, the button was made inline a bit further in my code. The problem now is that because the button is a block it won't center with the text.